# Can no longer deploy to Amazon AWS using VS 2010

Tags: amazon-ec2

Did something change on Amazon recently?

I'm trying to redeploy to my Amazon instance, and the "Publish to Amazon Cloudformation" plugin for VS 2010 no longer appears to update my instance. It tells me that upload is successful, but my instance does not appear to be updating on Amazon

I've tried disabling all my instances and using the tool to create a new instance , but no luck.

I do see that the URL of the deployed application (which for example looks like this: http://ec2-107-20-11-27.compute-1.amazonaws.com) does not appear to match up with the public IP of my instance on Amazon. (even when it creates a new one)

This seems to indicate that something might be broken.

any clues?

(btw, whenever the Amazon VS2010 Plugin creates a new instance, I am sure to reconnect my elastic IP with the new instance)

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded the latest version of the AWS toolkit and that resolved the problem.

Well, I couldn't *tell* it was the latest version, but it looks different now, so it must be.